# seed generates a different wallet

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I was restoring my wallet from seed and my 25 word seed is generating a different primary address from the original wallet I created (and funded).
Seed's words are in Italian.
25th word is the same of 24th.
I tried with 24-word (without the last) and the result is the same primary address.
I tried to restore from CLI and from GUI with same result.
I'm sure that I didn't use an offset passphrase when I generated the wallet.
I tried to change language of GUI app to Italian and to English with same output (always the same primary address that doesn't match my original one).
Please help.... maybe I lost funds?

Comment: Ok I understand that last word is the checksum and always repeats one of the 24 seed words

Comment: Seed words *always* produce the same main address. Perhaps you're using a set of seed words for a different wallet or are confusing the main address with a separate sub/account address in the wallet.

Comment: Main address (primary address) is the same of the Wallet. I've never created a sub address in my account. Anyway.. when I write "balance" in the wallet I should see my funds. I can't understand why I have one seed that now is generating a brand new wallet. I created a wallet (offline, cold) then I wrote paper backups of the seed. After this I saved watchonly wallet. I sent funds to the primary address. Now I wanted to recover the wallet and I found this surprise: a brand new wallet. So strange. I haven't other keys

Comment: "when I write balance I should see my funds" <- Not seeing funds can be an entirely different situation. `address all` will show your wallet addresses, irrespective of whether your wallet has scanned the blockchain and thus shows your correct balance.

Comment: Yes of course. In the watchonly wallet I see my balance and my address (I have just one, the primary address) but in the recover-from-seed wallet I see another wallet, another primary address... So it is a different wallet.

Comment: Is it possible that generating a wallet in a cold air-gapped computer (no internet connection) has produced an incoherent wallet?

Comment: No, there's no internet connection involved in creating a wallet. What version and type (GUI/CLI) did you use to create the original wallet? And are you sure you didn't create an encrypted seed, so with a passphrase? If your seed had a passphrase and you restore without (or with the wrong passphrase) you'll get a different wallet and address.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used monero wallet CLI 0.17 release or 0.16 I don't remember (from getmonero.org)... but I tried to restore using seed using both release and even 0.15 to check if it changes. Really I don't remember if I used an encrypted seed... It seems strange to me because I don't know how to do it but now it seems the unique way. It is simple to use a passphrase recovering from seed because the CLI asks the passphrase at the end of the last word but how to do an encryption of seed in wallet generation?

Comment: "It seems strange to me..." there's nothing strange. If you requested an encrypted seed you would have been asked to enter a passphrase. When you restore from a seed it asks for the passphrase. If your seed was encrypted then enter the passphrase used and if you didn't request an encrypted seed don't enter a passphrase when prompted.

Comment: im in the same problem, how you finally resolve it ? did you get yours funds again ? the restore wallet shows me a different primary address, please any light in this problem